# Drawbacks of using a single table to hold all relations

Tags: postgresql, table, relations

Say I have a simple user table that has some unique columns like id and email,
and a "level" column that defines the level of the user, such as admin, or moderator. Level is a fixed set of values (array constant in the code).

And another column called `group` that defines to what group that this user belong. Group is a variable set, meaning that a group can be created or deleted, just like a user.

I have seen 2 types of implementations for this type of data structure.

#### 1. storing all relations in one table:

```
users(
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  email STRING,
  level STRING,
  group STRING,
)

groups(
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  name STRING
)
```

#### 2. Having relations between multiple tables

```
users(
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  email STRING,
  level STRING,
  group INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(group) REFERENCES groups(id)
)

groups(
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  name STRING,
)
```

#### 3. Having relations between multiple tables + some apparently unneeded relations for the constants too

```
users(
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  email STRING,
  level INTEGER,
  group INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(level) REFERENCES levels(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(group) REFERENCES groups(id)
)

groups(
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  name STRING,
)

; this table would never get queried
levels(
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  name STRING,
)
```

I know that the "proper" way to do it is #2 (or maybe 3), but I was wondering why? What are the actual drawbacks of the first method? Are the only reasons data duplication and no data integrity check through fk? Because in the real world, data size does not seem to be an issue, and data integrity is usually handled by the application that uses the db, not the db itself. Also, the first method seems to be faster because you get all the data without having to use joins. So if it's only data duplication + no integrity vs performance, then its not so obvious why 2 or 3 are prefered.

Comment: I think you're mixing up _relations_ (which are colloquially known as "tables") and _relationships_ between entities. This makes your question a bit confusing.